# JS/HTML function

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please help me understand why the function writeOptions logs optionCounter twice?

```
console.log("<option values=" + optionCounter + ">"+optionCounter);
```

Why is there a second optionCounter placed after the option element?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function writeOptions(startNumber,endNumber)
    {
        var optionCounter;
        for(optionCounter = startNumber;
           optionCounter <= endNumber; optionCounter++)
            {
                document.write("<option value=" + optionCounter + ">" + optionCounter);
            }
    }

    function writeMonthOptions()
    {
        var theMonth;
        var monthCounter;
        var theDate = new Date(1);
        for(monthCounter = 0; monthCounter < 12; monthCounter++)
            {
                theDate.setMonth(monthCounter);
                theMonth = theDate.toString();
                theMonth = theMonth.substr(4,3);
                document.write("<option value=" + theMonth + ">" + theMonth);
            }
    }

    function recalcDateDiff()
    {
        var myForm = document.form1;
        var firstDay = 
            myForm.firstDay.options[myForm.firstDay.selectedIndex].value;

        var secondDay = 
            myForm.secondDay.options[myForm.secondDay.selectedIndex].value;

        var firstMonth =
            myForm.firstMonth.options[myForm.firstMonth.selectedIndex].value;

        var secondMonth = 
            myForm.secondMonth.options[myForm.secondMonth.selectedIndex].value;

        var firstYear =
            myForm.firstYear.options[myForm.firstYear.selectedIndex].value;

        var secondYear = 
            myForm.secondYear.options[myForm.secondYear.selectedIndex].value;

        var firstDate = 
            new Date(firstDay + " " + firstMonth + " " + firstYear);

        var secondDate = new Date(secondDay + " " + secondMonth + " " + secondYear);

        var daysDiff = (secondDate.valueOf() - firstDate.valueOf());

        daysDiff = Math.floor(Math.abs((((daysDiff/1000)/60)/60)/24));
        myForm.txtDays.value = daysDiff;

    }

    function window_onload()
    {
        var theForm = document.form1;
        var nowDate = new Date();
        theForm.firstDay.options[nowDate.getDate() - 1].selected =true;
        theForm.secondDay.options[nowDate.getDate() - 1].selected = true;
        theForm.firstMonth.options[nowDate.getMonth() - 1].selected = true;
        theForm.secondMonth.options[nowDate.getMonth() - 1].selected = true;
        theForm.firstYear.options[nowDate.getFullYear() - 1970].selected = true;
        theForm.secondYear.options[nowDate.getFullYear() - 1970].selected = true;


    }

    </script>
```

as you can see this is the entire Javascript codeblock for this particular example.

Comment: Provide your entire js

Answer (score 0):

I believe you know HTML. Each `<option>` tag has a display text (or label) and a value. And your code is creating the html option tag with both. So, when you write:

```
document.write("<option value=" + optionCounter + ">" + optionCounter);
```

the first `optionCounter` is for value and second one is for label/display text.

**Note**: I don't see the option tag being closed which could result in issues if not handled properly by the browser, so modify the statement as follows to render correct HTML:

```
document.write("<option value=" + optionCounter + ">" + optionCounter + "</option>");
```

Refer more about [select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) & [option tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)  on w3schools.com.